# Passed review audit while confirmation dialog still on screen

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I was reviewing first posts, and [came across a non-answer](https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/90920). I clicked <kbd>Delete</kbd>, and this happened:

[image: Delete-confirmation dialog superimposed over "Congratulations!"]

I never got a chance to click <kbd>OK</kbd> before being notified I passed the review audit.

Shouldn't I be notified I passed the review audit *after* clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>, and not *before*?

Seen on Firefox 23.0.1 on Fedora 19.

Comment: Oooo, a downvote. Does somebody disagree with ... uh ... I don't understand it at all!

Comment: @Michael maybe because there's no red line in the shape of a circle or oval?

Comment: Oh, so it's because people can't read. Makes sense.

Comment: you should try using jQuery. That might help.

Comment: You can't parse English with jQuery. Because English can't be parsed with jQuery. jQuery is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse English. As I have answered in English-and-jQuery questions here so many times before, the use of jQuery will not allow you to consume English. jQuery is a tool that is insufficiently sophisticated to understand the constructs employed by English. English is not a data structure and hence cannot be parsed by jQuery, so many times but it is not getting to me. Even Jon Skeet cannot parse English with jQuery. You will never make me crack.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: -1 not enough zalgo.